# Getting specific elements attribute with lxml

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have the following xml file , i need to reach a specific block and change 2 attributes values.

The xml file - https://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/activemq/assembly/src/release/conf/jetty.xml.shtml

I have it locally.

**The block i need to edit :**

```
<bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                <property name="contextPath" value="/admin" />
                <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/admin" />
                <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true" />
            </bean>
```

I need to change the value of attributes `<property name="contextPath" value="/admin" />`

and

```
<property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/admin" />
```

to

```
<property name="contextPath" value="/hawtio" />
```

And

```
<property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/hawtio" />
```

I also need to do it without using indexing , I need to do it using xpath.

Which means , i expect to use xpath to reach the specific element and change its attributes
without using (for example) tree[i]

My python code (or atleast what i expect to do)

```
import lxml
from lxml import etree

#Initialise xml file , xml file has namespaces
tree = etree.parse("jetty.xml")
myroot = tree.getroot()

#XML File has atleast 5 childs to each element
#From here i expect to edit attributes without using
#Manual indexing , for example

#prop = myroot.find('property[@name="contextPath"]')
#prop.attrib['value'] = '/hawtio'
#prop = myroot.find(('./property[@name="resourceBase"]'))
#prop.attrib['value'] = "${activemq.home}/webapps/hawtio"
#etree.write("jetty.xml", pretty_print=True)
```

Again , i am parsing a file which has namespaces and alot of child elements , running `find()` returns None and running `findall()`
returns an empty list , running those options with a namespaces also returns empty list \ None

Further explanation - Open an xml file , find specific elements and edit their attributes **NO MATTER** their index (myroot[0][2] for example) and write the changes back to the file.

Cheers,

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I ran print(tree.find("{http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans}bean[7]/{http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans}property/{http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans}list/{http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans}bean[1]/{http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans}property[1]")) but it prints Element at 0x.... , i need the full path , like a /path/to/element , in order to save it in a variable and then run .set() to change its attribute values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below (no external library is used)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


xml = '''<bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                <property name="contextPath" value="/admin" />
                <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/admin" />
                <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true" />
            </bean>'''
            
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
prop = root.find('./property[@name="contextPath"]')
prop.attrib['value'] = 'new_value_goes_here'
ET.dump(root)
```

output

```
<bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
                <property name="contextPath" value="new_value_goes_here" />
                <property name="resourceBase" value="${activemq.home}/webapps/admin" />
                <property name="logUrlOnStart" value="true" />
            </bean>
```

Comment: Good morning balderman! I appreciate your time and answer , this does indeed WORK , 
Here is what i've done in order to complete my task 

root = etree.fromstring(xml)
prop = root.find('./property[@name="contextPath"]')
prop.attrib['value'] = '/hawtio'
prop = root.find(('./property[@name="resourceBase"]'))
prop.attrib['value'] = "${activemq.home}/webapps/hawtio"
etree.dump(root)

However , i am parsing an actual xml file which needs to be edited using a script.
Is there a way to create a block like in your answer and apply that specific block at
the xml file in a specific point?

Comment: @M4CHINE Try to adopt my solution to your script. All you need to do is to parse a file, replace attrib values (based on my code), save the file. Take control from here. Feel free to vote up.

Comment: Perhaps i am missing something in your solution , Could you further explain?
ill edit the post to explain the steps i am doing.

Comment: My code finds the property with the name "contextPath" and replace the value with another value.

Answer (score 0):

Using baldermans answer i was able to find a workaround.

```
import lxml
from lxml import etree 

#Initialise xml file
tree = etree.parse("jetty.xml")
myroot = tree.getroot()

test = myroot.find('.//*[@name="contextPath"]')
print(test)
```

Yields:

```
Element {http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans}property at
```

Getting attribs:

```
print(test.attrib)
{'name': 'contextPath', 'value': '/admin'}
```

Changing values:

```
prop = myroot.find('.//*[@name="contextPath"]')
prop.attrib['value'] = '/hawtio'
prop = myroot.find(('.//*[@name="resourceBase"]'))
prop.attrib['value'] = "${activemq.home}/webapps/hawtio"
etree.write("jetty.xml", pretty_print=True)
```

I used the `.//*` option on `find()` with `[@name="contextPath"]`
Because i was aware there was only one occurrence of element `contextPath`
And therefore my solution is not great if another contextPath element is added to the file in the future , if you find a better solution than mine please post it.

**EDIT:**

Just noticed the file was updated , here is an update

```
prop = myroot.findall('.//*[@name="contextPath"]')
for i in prop:
     if '/admin' in i.attrib.itervalues():
          prop.attrib['value'] = '/hawtio'
          
prop = myroot.findall(('.//*[@name="resourceBase"]'))
for i in prop:
     if '${activemq.home}/webapps/admin' in i.attrib.itervalues():
          prop.attrib['value'] = '${activemq.home}/webapps/hawtio'
```

Since the attributes are returned as key-values we can use the built in dict `itervalues()` function to target specific keys.